How to have separate username/password for each database in mysql?
When I install MySql server, root user is initialized. It has no password.
I have a query here.
Suppose I create few databases in the mysql server. Do all these databases have same user now ie root user?
How can I have separate username/password for each of these databases?

in MySQL , user accounts are managed through the server level not the database server it self what this is means that you cannot directly assign different unernames and password for each database . instead MySQL uses user accounts to control access across the entire server including a specified database.
By default the root user is created  as superadmin by default with full privileges and access , also it has no password set.
However you can achieve the goal of having different usernames and passwords for accessing different databases with the help of MySQL user managment and the access privileges, here's how you can achieve the disired result
1_ first of all create a different MYSQL user account with each has unique credentials that you want to assign.
-- Create a user 'exampleuser1' with password 'password1'
CREATE USER 'exampleuser1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';

or you can simply create the provided users through the phpmyadmin provided gui in user account section
2_ then grant specific Privileges for each user included the database they should be able to access to.
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.* TO 'exampleuser1'@'localhost';

in this example i let the exampleuser1 have all the privileges , adjust the privileges as per requirements of each user.
For example :
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON db1.* TO 'exampleuser1'@'localhost';

also you can revoke a privilege from a user , you can simply use the 'REVOKE' statement with the provileges.

So to grant privileges only for a specific db, I need this: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1.myawesomedb TO 'exampleuser1'@'localhost';

There is one major problem here  ,this command grants privileges to the user on a specific table (myawesomedb) within a database (db1). The part before the dot (.) specifies the database (db1), and after the dot (.), the name (myawesomedb) specifies the table. So, exampleuser1 will receive privileges to myawesomedb table, not to the entire db1 database.
if you want to give the all privileges to a certain user in your database .
use : GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myawesomedb TO 'exampleuser1'@'localhost';
make sur to replace myawesomedb with your actual db name

In the default setting, the root user has full privileges to access all databases on the server
When a database is created and a user is not automatically created with it, by default the root user accesses the database.
But this can be controlled by creating groups with a different user name and password
The following steps explain how this is possible :
To create separate username/password combinations for different databases, you can follow these steps:
1 Log in to your MySQL server as root user:
mysql -u root -p

2 To create a new user use CREATE USER. For example, to create a user named "user" with a password:
Create user 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

3 Then specify the privileges you want using the GRANT statement. To continue the previous example, to grant all privileges to "user" in a database called "database1":
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';

4 Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each rule set for which you want to create separate users.
A final note: It is recommended to set a password for the root user
I recommend How To Create a New User and Grant Permissions in MySQL because it provides more detailed information about the topic
